# iOS / Objective c - UITabBarControllerDelegate - Custom tab animation delegates not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uiviewanimation

I am trying to create a custom tabbar animation when a user taps on a tab bar button.

I have implemented a UITabBarController subclass that implements UITabBarControllerDelegate

here is the .m

```
#import "MYCustomTabBarControler.h"


@interface MYCustomTabBarControler ()

@end

@implementation MYCustomTabBarControler

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.delegate = self; // I set the delegate as self

}


#pragma mark - UITabBarControllerDelegate

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    //This is called so I know the delegate is working 
    NSLog(@"The tabBarController delegate is set and working");
    return YES;
}

//This delegate method is never called 
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
           UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                             toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {


    MYBarTransition *animator = [MYBarTransition new];
    return animator;

}

//This delegate method is never called 
- (id<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
                     interactionControllerForAnimationController:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationController {

    MYBarTransition *animator = [MYBarTransition new];
    return animator;
}
```

For some reason the delegate methods responsible for transitioning are NOT called. I have read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarControllerDelegate/tabBarController:interactionControllerForAnimationController:) and can't see any reason they would not be called.

I have set my delegate correctly and confirmed it is
working by implementing the shouldSelectViewController method

What am I missing here?

Comment: When do you expect it to be called?

Comment: Should it not be called when the user taps the tab bar button ?

Comment: I expect it to be called when a user taps on the tab bar button.. but it isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong delegate method for what you are trying to accomplish. Try using:

```
- (nullable id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
            animationControllerForTransitionFromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                              toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC;
```

This will be called when the user taps on a different tab.

Comment: LOL. Yes. I'm going to go lay my head in shame for a few hours